# Line 8: Parsing error: this is a reserved word

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a detail page about each item from the API; however it doesn't seem to work, it gives me a "Line 8:  Parsing error: this is a reserved word" error. Also I'm not sure if my code in the DetailPage.js works properly, I want to get the the data about the clicked item on the home page on the detail page so I check if the ID matches any of the ones from the API.

My App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter,Route,Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Brewery from './components/Brewery'
import DetailPage from './components/DetailPage'
import Menu from './components/Menu'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <div> <Menu /> </div>
      <div>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/brewery" component={Brewery} exact/>
            <Route path="/brewery/:id" component={DetailPage} exact/>
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

My Brewery.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class Brewery extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      breweries: []
    };
    }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({
          breweries: data,
        })
      })
  }

  render() {

    const { breweries } = this.state;

    return(
        <ul>
          {breweries.slice(0,10).map((brewery) =>
              <li key={brewery.id}>
                <Link to={`/brewery/${ brewery.id }`}>
                  {brewery.name}
                </Link>
              </li>
          )}
        </ul>
    )
  }
}

export default Brewery;
```

My DetailPage.js

```
import React from "react";
import Brewery from './Brewery'

class DetailPage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const paramsId = `${this.props.match.params.id}`
    return(
        {this.state.breweries.map((brewery) => {
          if (brewery.id === paramsId) {
            return <div>{brewery.name}</div>
        }})
    )
  }
}
}

export default DetailPage;
```

Comment: `return(        {` makes no sense; `{}` interpolation only works inside a JSX tag.  To return a Javascript expression, return it directly.

Comment: How exactly can I fix the return though?

Comment: By returning your Javascript expression, just like any other function.

Answer (score 2):

As @SLaks pointed out in the comments, you don't need the curlies (`{}`) when using Javascript expressions out of your JSX. Just write your expressions directly.

```
render() {
  // You don't need to use curlies here.
  console.log("foo");
  return (
    // or here if you start your return statement with a Javascript expression.
    foo.map(el => <div>{Here you need it if it is a JS expression}</div>)
  );
}
```

So drop the top curlies in the return part of `DetailPage` component. But after that, you will encounter another problem not related to your current issue. In your `DetailPage` you don't have any state of `breweries`. You are fetching them in your `Brewery` component. So, you don't have them in the `DetailPage` component. You have an id coming from your router, so as a naive approach you can use it again to fetch a single brewery.

So:

```
class DetailPage extends React.Component {
  state = {
    brewery: {}
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const { id } = this.props.match.params;
    fetch(`https://api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries/${id}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          brewery: data
        });
      });
  }
  render() {
    return <p>{this.state.brewery.name}</p>;
  }
}
```